# How can I check a type's dependents order to drop them and replace/modify the initial type?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I tried to modify a type using the following code and it gave me the error code: '**ORA-02303**'. I don't know much about Oracle or PL/SQL but I need to solve this; so I'd appreciate any further help with this.

Thanks in advance. The code is just an example. But then again, I need to check its dependents first.

```
create or replace type A as object (
  x_ number, 
  y_ varchar2(10),
  member procedure to_upper
);
/
```

Comment: Note that you might have two problems here: a) TYPE dependants, or b) TABLE dependants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's available in the data dictionary somewhere, but not sure where off-hand; and you're likely to have lots of dependencies that aren't easy to resolve. But you may be able to modify the existing type instead: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_4002.htm

There's also a `FORCE` option but that could still invalidate dependent objects.

Answer (score 4):

Look in `DBA_DEPENDENCIES, ALL_DEPENDENCIES, or USER_DEPENDENCIES` as appropriate:

```
SELECT OWNER, NAME, TYPE
  FROM DBA_DEPENDENCIES 
 WHERE REFERENCED_OWNER = [type owner]
   AND REFERENCED_NAME  = [type name]
   AND REFERENCED_TYPE  = 'TYPE'
/
```

Comment: You should also look at table dependencies as they can also stop you recreating the type.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use DROP with FORCE, as it will automatically modify tables (delete columns) and god know what else to validate everything.
Use something like:

```
ALTER TYPE type_name DROP ATTRIBUTE attr_name INVALIDATE;
ALTER TYPE type_name ADD ATTRIBUTE attr_name varchar2(50) CASCADE;
```

This will work on types with table/type dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you've used the type in a table you should be able to see it through a query like :

```
select * from all_tab_columns
where data_type_owner not in ('SYS');
```

But I'd start off looking at Alex's suggestion of using ALTER TYPE

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by basic restrictions in Oracle, another reason not to use oracle types in the database.

**For 'TYPE' dependencies you can:**

1. DROP TYPE mytype FORCE;
2. Then re-create the type mytype and type body
3. Then DROP TYPE mytype_dependent FORCE;
4. Then re-create the mytype_dependent type and type body.
5. Repeat for all dependent and referenced types.

Note: The items 3..5 are required because dependent types cannot be automatically recompiled or manually compiled 'in place'.

**For 'TABLE' dependencies you must:**

Use the guidance in the article here, where it talks about the three relevant scenarios.

[ORA-02303: cannot drop or replace a type with type or table dependents](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/06/ora-02303-cannot-drop-or-replace-type.html)

from the [Annals of Oracle's Improbable Errors](http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/) blog